# Why is Django (./manage runserver) serving files I've deleted?

Tags: django, gunicorn, django-staticfiles

In my development environment I've deleted my static files directory (`rm -rf [PROJECT_NAME]/static/`), emptied my browser's cache, restarted the server and still when I load a page, the static files (my JS, CSS, etc.) are **still** there (e.g. `http://192.168.1.100:8000/static/js/bootstrap.min.js`). I can't figure out how. This happens with both `runserver` and `gunicorn`. How are they still being served and how can I stop them from being served?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of [STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root) variable in Django settings.py file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestion but `STATIC_ROOT` looks properly configured: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')`.

Comment: What about [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS).

Comment: Aha! That's it. I misunderstood how `STATICFILES_DIRS` works. Re-read the docs and now it makes sense. I thought these were just directories that were crawled when running `./manage.py collectstatic` and didn't realize that the `STATICFILES_FINDERS` were used as the server ran. Glad to discover I only need to run `collectstatic` in production (I'm using Heroku along with Amazon S3) and not during development. Thanks a lot for your help @pxl!